# TPT job seems to ignore the TargetMaxSessions parameter

Tags: teradata

I' moving data between 2 teradata instances using a tdload command. It's working but because adminstration team complains about too much sessions I'm trying to restrict TPT to use just 1 session on source database and 1 session on target database by giving the TargetMaxSessions and SourceMaxSessions parameters. In source-DB that seems to work, but in target-DB I always see 26 sessions!
Can please anybody give me a hint? Thank you in advance!

Database Version for both DBs is 16.20.

Here the structure of my tdload command:

```
tdload --SourceTdpid xx.xxx.xxx.xx --SourceUserName MYUSER  --SourceUserPassword  '$tdwallet(MYUSER_pw)' \
       --SourceTable MYDB.MYTABLE \
       --TargetTdpid yyy.yy.yy.yy  --TargetUserName MYUSER2 --TargetUserPassword '$tdwallet(MYUSER2_pw)' \
       --TargetTable MYDB.MYTABLE --TargetWorkingDatabase MYDB \
       --TargetMaxSessions 1 --SourceMaxSessions 1 --LoadInstances 1 \
       -S myjob > MYDB_MYTABLE.log 2>&1
```

TPT has generated this parameter file, so it seems to have understood my command (but still getting 26 target sessions):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The number of sessions is usually not controlled by Min/MaxSessions but by Workload Management.

Most operators support a parameter setting the load size using querybanding, e.g.

```
QueryBandSessInfo = 'UtilityDataSize=SMALL;'
```

is the pre-defined option with the smallest number of sessions.

Approach your admin team, maybe they defined other values, e.g. a value requesting a single session (Of course, they should have told you that when they complained about too many sessions).

Comment: Aditional question: Do you know what these MaxSessions-parameters are good for?

Comment: They were used before TDWM, i.e. they're legacy (on most systems)